# powershell : how to format get-date to string and remove 0's?

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to eliminate leading any leading zeroes in my date when I run the get-date cmdlet by trying:

```
$filedate = get-date -uformat "%m-%d-%Y" 
$filedate = $filedate.ToString().Replace("0", "")
```

this returns "01-04-2008"

I want to the output to be "1-4-2008"

any ideas on another way of doing this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$filedate = get-date -format "M-d-yyyy"
```

Answer (score 3):

$fileDate = $fileDate.ToString("M-d-yyyy")

Comment: (Get-Date).ToString("M-d-yyyy")

Answer (score 0):

use format string like :

```
get-date -format yyyy/M/d
```

or

get-date.tostring(yyyy/M/d)