# how to write a powershell command to get a formatted date?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I would like to know how to use Get-Date command in windows powershell to get the date format in following way.

Tue 27/01/2015 20:10:21

Comment: possible duplicate of [powershell : how to format get-date to string and remove 0's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341471/powershell-how-to-format-get-date-to-string-and-remove-0s)

Comment: but i need to get the day of the week as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Date -Format "ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
```

or

```
(Get-Date).ToString("ddd dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```